# Setting an object's value

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I'm toying around with objects in javascript since I'm learning how to do OOP in JavaScript, and coming from C#, I see it is a quite different story in here.

Here's my code so far:

```
/*JavaScript Objects*/

var employee = new Object();

employee.firstName = "";
employee.lastName = "";
employee.salary = "";
employee.vacationDays = "";
employee.age = "";
employee.yearsWorking = "";

var getFirstName = function(firstName){
    this.value = firstName;
}
```

I'm not sure if the function is well put, and what I'm doing now, is going to console on Chrome and setting the firstName by calling the function like this:

```
employee.getFirstName("Brandon");
```

But for some reason, the property `firstName` is still `""`. Any thoughts on anything I can be doing wrong here?

Comment: Not `this.value = firstName;` but `this.firstName = firstName;`

Comment: BTW: Why do you call it 'getFirstName' when actually setting the value?

Comment: @u_mulder That still does not work. By the code posted the object referred to by `employee` simply does not have a `getFirstName()` method. There is just a variable storing a reference to a `Function` instance. As posted, `employee.getFirstName("Brandon")` throws a `TypeError` exception because “`undefined` is not a function” or “Object #<Object> has no method 'getFirstName'”. See [devtoolsecrets.com](http://devtoolsecrets.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this.

```
 var getFirstName = function(firstName){
      this.value = firstName;
  }
```

To:

```
 employee.getFirstName = function(firstName){
    this.firstName= firstName;
  }
```

Comment: This works well, as what I was intending to do. Thank you very much! Marking as answer as soon as the 5min pass.

Answer (score 1):

I know that answering with just a link is not the preferred way in SO but I don't think it is possible to transfer the necessary knowledge in just a few sentences - at least I'm not able to to do it in this case.

This [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) will guide you through your path from C# to OO javascript

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you are trying to set a value with a function named "getFirstName"
try that:

```
employee.getFirstName = function(firstName){
    this.firstName = firstName;
};
```